# python script not encoding to utf-8

Tags: python, json, csv, utf-8

I have this Python 3 script to read a json file and save as csv. It works fine except for the special characters like `\u00e9`. So `Montr\u00e9al` should be encoded like `Montréal`, but it is giving me `MontrÃ©al` instead.

```py
import json

ifilename = 'business.json'
ofilename = 'business.csv'

json_lines = [json.loads( l.strip() ) for l in open(ifilename).readlines() ]
OUT_FILE = open(ofilename, "w", newline='', encoding='utf-8')
root = csv.writer(OUT_FILE)
root.writerow(["business_id","name","neighborhood","address","city","state"])
json_no = 0
for l in json_lines:
    root.writerow([l["business_id"],l["name"],l["neighborhood"],l["address"],l["city"],l["state"]])
    json_no += 1

print('Finished {0} lines'.format(json_no))
OUT_FILE.close()
```

Comment: The problem is not with the output of the program, the problem is with the editor you're using to display the file. It isn't recognizing UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the csv file was displaying correctly when opening it with Notepad++ but not with Excel. So I had to import the csv file with Excel and specify 65001: Unicode (UTF-8).
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this at the top of the file

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Consider this example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-    
import sys

print("my default encoding is : {0}".format(sys.getdefaultencoding()))
string_demo="Montréal"
print(string_demo)

reload(sys) # just in python2.x
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8') # just in python2.x

print("my default encoding is : {0}".format(sys.getdefaultencoding()))
print(str(string_demo.encode('utf8')), type(string_demo.encode('utf8')))
```

In my case, the output is like this if i run in python2.x:

```
my default encoding is : ascii
Montréal
my default encoding is : UTF8
('Montr\xc3\xa9al', <type 'str'>)
```

but when i comment out the reload and setdefaultencoding lines, my output is like this:

```
my default encoding is : ascii
Montréal
my default encoding is : ascii
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(str(string_demo.encode('utf8')), type(string_demo.encode('utf8')))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It's most a problem with the editor, Python when it's a encode error raise a Exception.

Comment: It is still giving me MontrÃ©al

Comment: which version of python are you using?
as Mark says, it's most like a problem with your IDE

Comment: I'm using Anaconda - Spyder (Python 3.6)